# Analytical Console juts Logs "InternalRequestSender outbound"

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, analytics, ibm-mobile-services

Hi when ever i tried to use Android Debug Apk everything in my logs gets logged and everything works fine.
But if i try to use my release apk i only get only the below message in the logs i have verified my debugger level and its Debug and i have changed it to verify as well but still no luck.

1. Package wl.analytics
2. Level   Analytics
3. Message InternalRequestSender
   outbound

> We are using cordova-plugin-mfp: 8.0.2018090313
>
> Server MFP: 8.0.0.00-20171220-1341

Answer (score 0):

You mention the debugger level is set to Debug. Since it is in debug mode, only with a debug mode apk you will see the logs.
You should try with a different loglevel than debug, for instance `INFO` level. Make sure you use [setLevel](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.analytics.doc/analytics/t_adjusting_log_verbosity.html) API explicitly and override the default with the one you want.

Alernatively you can use customData too if it is not just logging purpose.

Comment: hi i am even using the Set level and setting it to 'Debug' explicitly in release mode still i am not receiving the logs. we are using customData but even that it just logs some not everything

Comment: i think i am not clear above i am getting logs in my debug Android build but not in my release build ???

Comment: "debug" will be visible in debug mode only. It wont be seen when you have a release build apk

Comment: thats right is there any way i can see that in release build ?? and also i already tried setting the logger level to debug / trace and it also doent help me receive information into client logs

Comment: debug statements cannot be seen in release builds.

Comment: so even i set the debugger level to Debug and send some analytics data we cant see those in the Client logs ? correct4